# will_paginate not getting the right number of pages when used with group option

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pagination, will-paginate

I am still stuck at a Rails 2.3.8 application. Recently I installed 'will_paginate' gem to make my life a bit easier with generating pages. It works really well most of the times, but when I set the `:group` option the number of pages is wrongly calculated.

example:

```
@items = Item.find(:all, :select => 'items.*, count(accounts_items.id) as users_count',:joins => 'join accounts_items on accounts.id = accounts_items.item_id', :group => 'items.id').paginate :page=>params[:page],:per_page=>12
```

When I checked the queries performed from the logs they looked like this:

> SELECT items.*, count(accounts_items.id) as users_count FROM `items` join accounts_items on items.id = accounts_items.item_id GROUP BY spaces.id ORDER BY users_count DESC LIMIT 0, 12
>
> SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM `items` join accounts_items on item.id = accounts_spaces.space_id

The first query works perfectly and gets me all the information needed for each item, while the second one is just not the right query to count my items.

Is there a way to fix this? If yes how?

Thanks a lot

Comment: i saw a similar question, maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790295/problem-with-named-scope-causes-error-in-will-paginate-how-to-include-group-by